# inserting records from a pivot table?

Tags: data-loader, upsert

Is there a way to upload records based on a pivot table? If I have three objects in Salesforce, Object A represent hardware item, Object B represent price plan and Object C. Object C stores the combinations of ObjectA and ObjectB, for example HardwareItem1 with pricePlan1.

For example if a have a spreadsheet with a pivot table layout as such: Colunna D,E,F all have record id's (relating to records in ObjectA), rows 10,11 & 12 all have record id's (relating to records in ObjectB), therefore the pivot table has cell values for ObjectC. I would like to create a set of records based on the cell values of the pivot so that I end up insterting 9 records.
[image]

Perhaps it is necessary to tranform the pivot into a tabular format,

Answer (score 2):

You will need to transform the pivot into a table with one row for each record you want inserted. Each column should correspond to a field on the target object.

Answer (score -1):

Yes,we can create pivot table in Visualforce Page  using javascript
for details http://gourangasadhukhan.blogspot.in/2014/11/how-to-create-pivot-table-in-forcecom.html

Comment: While using links is helpful, they don't typically last forever and would make your answer useless when that happens.  It's a good idea to take the important information from the links and put it into the content of your answer.